# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] wrong value

Tags: php, url

I'm using this variable to get the current page URL, like this:

```
  $request = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

  $page = (is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http').'://';
  if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
    $page .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$request;
  else $page .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$request;
```

The app. I doing this for is public, and the problem is that on some sites (very rare) this variable returns the entire URL, including the domain name, not just the requested page. Is this a server misconfiguration?

Comment: Can u tell us what web server engines are running in those "very rare" faulty instances where your app is deployed? Apache, lighttpd, nginx?

Comment: Probably Apache. Anyway I think I found the issue. This app. is for WordPress and the user has a WP plugin called WPML, which is either messing around with redirects or it's changing this variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be somewhere in your code (or 3rd party package) is changing this variable.

You could `grep`.

```
grep -r -E '\$_SERVER\[[\'"]?REQUEST_URI[\'"]?\]\s?=[^=]+?'
```

That regex should find where `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI]` is being assigned, and not just used normally or testing for equality, for example. Note too I removed the `-i` flag because [PHP variables are case sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) and [so are array keys](http://codepad.org/qj1D1msx).